# Abstract Class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, abstract, delphi-2009

I am using a component suite which has many abstract classes. Now I want to apply polymorphism but I am getting Error Abstract Class when I create my object.

Should I override all methods which are virtual even if I don't need it? Are there any workaround or solution?

Comment: Do you get "Error Abstract Class" at run time or compile time? Compile time should give E2402: Constructing instance of abstract class '%s'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to make an instance of a class, you need to override all methods that are declared as virtual abstract. Even if you don't use them.

If you really want a work around, you can use empty methods. But I won't recommend that.

And to add some more information on the subject:

A method is abstract if it is declared with virtual abstract:

```
procedure MyMethod(const AMyParameter: Integer); virtual; abstract;
```

Trivia: You can even override a method as abstract:

```
procedure MyMethod(const AMyParameter: Integer); override; abstract;
```

You need to override these methods in order to instantiate from that class.

And you can declare an entire class as abstract:

```
type
  TMyClass = class abstract (TMyAncestor)
  end;
```

You get a warning if you try to instantiate that class.

The counterpart is a sealed class:

```
type
  TMyClass = class sealed (TMyAncestor)
  end;
```

You get a warning if you try to inherit from that class.

You can also seal methods, but you need the keyword final for that.

```
procedure MyMethod(const AMyParameter: Integer); override; final;
```

Comment: I think you don't have to implement all abstract methods given that you don't call them. It just gives you a compiler warning. If called at runtime an `EAbstractError` is raised.

Comment: I think you need to check the facts stated in this answer

Comment: Note that you will only get a warning if you try to implement them directly using the abstract class name, e.g. `Obj := TAbstractObject.Create;`. If you use 'class of' variables or methods that return a class type it is possible to get abstract errors without a compile time warning. e.g. `TAbstractClass = class of TAbstractObject; function GetClass: TAbstractClass;  ... Obj := GetClass.Create; // <-- boom`

Comment: "Even if you don't use them" - meh.... I don't know about this.! So, you have a parent class (T0) that has a T0.LockDoor() abstract method. And you have 9 child classes that implement the abstract method of the parent. But the 10th class is a bit special and does not need to implement it. It has a StartEngine() method instead ... [to be continued ...]

Comment: [Continuation] ....... So, you implement T10.LockDoor  as an empty method and then you call it in your program (by accident) thinking that your door is locked. I personally would let this method unimplemented in T10. If it is called by accident, you will get an EAbstract error during your testing, and you will know that T10.LockDoor was called instead of T10.StartEngine.

Answer (score 8):

Delphi doesn't have abstract classes as such, only abstract methods. You will get an abstract method exception raised if you call an abstract method.

Put simply you must not call abstract methods. The compiler emits a warming if it detects you instantiating a class with abstract methods. Good practise is to ask the compiler to turn these warnings into errors.

Comment: `Good practise is to ask the compiler to turn these warnings into errors.` and how do we do this?

Comment: @David, not exactly, you can create an abstract class (even without abstract methods) using the TMyClass = class abstract (TMyParent)...

Comment: @johan project options, hints and warnings, any warming can be converted into an error

Comment: @David, way cool didn't know that you could upgrade your warnings.

Comment: "Good practise is to ask the compiler to turn these warnings into errors." Good practice - true. IMO better practice is to use interfaces instead, which force you to implement them if used.

Comment: Bringing the answer up to date: nowadays, a class can be marked as "abstract": http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)

Comment: @Z80 I don't think that marking a class as abstract does very much. Isn't it a hangover from the .net days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Tested. You are right. You can instantiate the class and call its methods. The compiler won't cry hints or warnings.

Comment: From Delphi help: "Note: Delphi allows instantiating a class declared abstract, for backward compatibility, but this feature should not be used anymore". What do they mean by "this feature"? The "abstract" or the instantiation? I guess is the second one.

Comment: @ServerOverflow it relates to the discontinued delphi .net compiler which needed to support classes declared  abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Your descendant class is still abstract if

1. it's declared `abstract`, or
2. it has at least one method declared abstract, or
3. it doesn't override and implement all abstract methods from its ancestors

Comment: Yeah - I've found that it's easier to only abstract those methods that will always have to be overridden.  All the other stuff gets 'empty' virtual methods.  That said, why is TThread.execute not abstract?  <g>

Comment: @Martin James: You are right, it should actually be abstract, but imagine it were and somebody instantiated a TThread descendant and forgot to override Execute: An EAbstractError would be raised in a background thread and would not be handled, so nobody would realize what happened. It's not easy to find this kind of error.

Comment: @ondrej - Checks comments in the answer above. Marking the whole class as abstract does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It will produce an error if you override the abstract constructor as it automatically puts inherited into the new constructor which of course is calling the abstract constructor if you use the code auto complete.

e.g.

```
type
  TMyclass = class (TObject)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); dynamic; abstract;
  end;

  TMyclass2 = class(TMyclass)
  public
    Constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyclass2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

end;
```