# Delphi abstract class avoid implementation

Tags: delphi

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187018/abstract-class-in-delphi) question you see that is possible to create an abstract class adding the `abstract` keywrod. I am translating a project in Delphi but I see that it allows the creation of an abstract class. This is the code:

```
type
 TCableSPF = class abstract
  //code
end;
```

This is an abstract class of course and I have a lot of subclasses that implement it. By the way I see that is it possible to create an instance of this like;

```
a := TCableSPF.Create;
```

When I try to call its methods that are virtual and abstract I get the error and this is ok but can I prevent the creation of the class? Or Delphi allows this by default? thanks for the help

Comment: This is a known issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10235

Comment: After some Googling, I found an option `{$WARN CONSTRUCTING_ABSTRACT ERROR}`, however, I took a look at [RADStudio's Tokyo documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects) (referenced in the link showed by @SebastianProske), and unfortunately found the following note: "_Delphi allows instantiating a class declared abstract, for backward compatibility, but this feature should not be used anymore_". :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `class abstract` is a holdover from the `Delphi for .Net` days.
For reasons unknown there is no (current) implementation behind this keyword.

If you want to prevent instantiation of an abstract class, this keyword will not help. Instead do the following:

```
type
  TCableSPF = class abstract
  //code
strict protected
  //Define all constructors for an abstract class as protected.
  constructor Create; virtual; reintroduce;
end;
```

By defining all constructors as protected, only descendent object can access the constructor, other code cannot access the constructor.
Because you reintroducing the virtual constructor, you also cannot instantiate it using:

```
unit A; 

type
  TMyAbstractObject = class abstract(TObjectX)
  strict protected
    constructor Create; virtual; reintroduce;
  end;

...
unit B;

  TMyClass = class of TObjectX;

  AbstractObjectInstance = TMyClass.Create;  //Will not work for TMyAbstractObject
```

Note that you should **not** declare the constructor `override`. Instead declare it `virtual reintroduce` (or just `reintroduce` if you don't want to allow virtual constructors).

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the same thing that C++ does because it doesn't have the abstract keyword. Btw, I have to use a workaround I see. I hope they will fix this because it is annoying :/

Comment: why should I reintroduce and not override? Is that because the definition that abstract has no implementation?

Comment: There was implementation behind it in the .net compiler.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli, declaring it `override` defeats the whole purpose because then you can instantiate a hidden constructor using a class of class constructor (what other languages call a class factory construct) using the virtual nature of the constructor.

Comment: But you receive a warning when you try to instantiate a class marked as `abstract`, don't you? If so, then I would stress enough to resolve compiler warnings (have no Delphi by hand to verify right now).

Comment: Not necessarily, @Victoria. Creating an abstract class via a metaclass variable doesn't cause the compiler to issue a warning.